# Converse of Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, real-numbers

Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem (for sequences) states that Every bounded sequence has a limit point.
However the converse is not true i.e. there do exist unbounded sequence(s) having only one real limit point.
My query is, why are they writing it as "only one real limit point"?
I feel it should be "having a (atleast 1) real limit point".

Comment: $\{0,1,0,2,0,3...\}$ has only one real limit point, namley $0$.

Comment: Could you quote the exact statement that uses "*only one real limit point*" which you believe is incorrect?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem states that for any bounded sequence, there exists a convergent $\textbf{subsequence}$. From @geetha290krm example, by taking the odd term only which form a subsequence and constant zero-sequence so it must converging to zero.

Comment: You think the statement should have at least 1 limit point. It is correct for any counter-example of the converse of BWT. But actually, to disprove the converse statement, you only need one simple counter-example like if you find 'an' unbounded sequence which has one limit point only, then you are done !

Comment: My doubt is basically that the word "only" should be replaced by "atleast one".

Comment: @geetha290krm {-1,1,2,-2,1,2,-3,1,2,....} has two limit points although it is unbounded.

Comment: Of course, you can have infinitely many limit points also.

Comment: @RaminderSingh  You still don't say what is the exact statement where you think that "*the word "only" should be replaced by "atleast one"*". You probably think that must be self-evident somehow, but it is not.

Comment: @dxiv the line is "However the converse is not true i.e. there do exist unbounded sequence(s) having only one real limit point."

Comment: @RaminderSingh There is no "*only one*" in the theorem you quote, and there is no "*only one*" in its converse. The Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem states that "*every bounded sequence has a limit point*". It does not state that it has "*only one*" limit point, and that's obviously not true, either, take for example the bounded sequence $\,(-1)^n\,$ which has two limit points. The converse (which is not true, as you note) is that "*every sequence which has a limit point is bounded*". This includes all sequences that have one or more limit points, there is no "*only one*" in it.

Comment: @dxiv The line that I wrote above, I am talking of that. I feel in that line wherever it is written "only one", there it should be "a" instead. Again mentioning the line:  "However the converse is not true i.e. there do exist unbounded sequence(s) having only one real limit point."

Comment: @RaminderSingh Who wrote that line, and who claims that's equivalent to the converse? 1) The "*i.e.*" implies an equivalence, but "*there do exist unbounded sequence(s) having only one real limit point*" is not equivalent to the converse of the B-W theorem. The converse is, again, "*every sequence which has a limit point is bounded*". 2) The line becomes correct if either 2.a) you replace "i.e." with "e.g." or "*for example*", or 2.b) you replace "*only one*" with "*a*". 3) One counterexample is enough to prove the converse false, so an example with "*only one*" limit point is indeed enough.

Comment: I agree that it (that line) is not converse, all I was asking is that whatever is that line, the word "only one" should be replaced by "a". That's it.